# Recursively find the most recent file from each folder in folder hierarchy.

Tags: c#

I need to find the most recently created file from each folder under my root folder.
The following code returns all the files from the root folder:

```
list<string> capturesList = SafeFileEnumerator.EnumerateFiles(pathToSearch, "*.pcap", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
```

The class `SafeFileEnumerator` searches only the location with permissions:

```
public static class SafeFileEnumerator
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateDirectories(string parentDirectory, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOpt)
    {
        try
        {
            var directories = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
            if (searchOpt == SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            {
                directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(parentDirectory).SelectMany(x => EnumerateDirectories(x, searchPattern, searchOpt));
            }
            return directories.Concat(Directory.EnumerateDirectories(parentDirectory, searchPattern));
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFiles(string path, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOpt)
    {
        try
        {
            var dirFiles = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
            if (searchOpt == SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            {
                dirFiles = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path).SelectMany(x => EnumerateFiles(x, searchPattern, searchOpt));
            }

            return dirFiles.Concat(Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, searchPattern));
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to Get the most recently created file from each folder under the root folder you can yse that :

```
if(Directory.Exists("YourPath"))
foreach (string _tempFiles in Directory.GetDirectories("YourPath","*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                       .Select(directory => Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.*" )
                       .OrderByDescending(File.GetLastWriteTime)
                       .FirstOrDefault()))
{
 MessageBox.Show(_tempFiles);
}
```

this code to check only the folders in your root folder

Comment: what about location without permissions ? how can i do it with my class in my example ?

Comment: @user1269592 : if you haven't permission to the directory in "YourPath" then Directory.Exists("YourPath") will return false and if there's a directory in the root of "YourPath" without access to read will be skipped by Directory.GetDirectories

Comment: There's an overload of "GetDirectories", that accepts a SearchOption enum. Pass in SearchOption.AllDirectories, and it will recursively hit all directories under the root, not just the first layer.

Comment: can i have an example to recursively scan all the directories under the root directory ?