# Show the current directory while recursive search for files

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using this built in method in order to search files from directory:

```
foreach (string file in SafeFileEnumerator.EnumerateFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{

}
```

is it possible while search to display on my UI the current directory?

Comment: BackgroundWorker FTW.

Comment: Can i have an code example ?

Answer (score 1):

- If your `SafeFileEnumerator` is the Directory class then <strike>the answer is No</strike> just keep track of the result from `System.IO.Path.getDirectory(file)` and act when it changes.
- If it is the class from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14381656/60761), then you can change the code to raise an event.

Comment: This class act like SafeFileEnumerator  i.e show me the files in process before finish to search ?

Comment: To get a better answer, improve the question. What classes, what GUI, any threading used/desired?

Comment: System.IO.Path.getDirectory(file) working fine but can i get the most deep directory instead of the root ?

Comment: It should get you the full path (= deepest dir).